# Locate a Radio widget in a flutter unit test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to find the following radio button that is in my widget tree in a unit test?

From `debugDumpApp()` the widget I am trying to find is at the bottom of this snippet:

```
│      ├InkWell(gestures: [tap], clipped to BoxShape.rectangle, state: _InkResponseState<InkResponse>#e573c)
                              │      │└Actions(dispatcher: null, actions: {[<SelectAction>]: Closure: () => Action from Function '_createAction@613059085':., [<ActivateAction>]: Closure: () => Action from Function '_createAction@613059085':.})
                              │      │ └Focus(dependencies: [_FocusMarker], state: _FocusState#e7131)
                              │      │  └_FocusMarker
                              │      │   └Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, label: null, value: null, hint: null, hintOverrides: null, renderObject: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#e56d2 relayoutBoundary=up3)
                              │      │    └MouseRegion(listeners: [enter, exit], renderObject: RenderMouseRegion#61069 relayoutBoundary=up4)
                              │      │     └GestureDetector(startBehavior: start)
                              │      │      └RawGestureDetector(state: RawGestureDetectorState#51044(gestures: [tap], behavior: opaque))
                              │      │       └_GestureSemantics(renderObject: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#8ee96 relayoutBoundary=up5)
                              │      │        └Listener
                              │      │         └_PointerListener(listeners: [down], behavior: opaque, renderObject: RenderPointerListener#125af relayoutBoundary=up6)
                              │      │          └Row(direction: horizontal, mainAxisAlignment: start, crossAxisAlignment: center, dependencies: [Directionality], renderObject: RenderFlex#2d677 relayoutBoundary=up7)
                              │      │           ├Radio<String>(dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#eab41], _InheritedTheme], state: _RadioState<String>#e39e8(tickers: tracking 4 tickers))
```

The unit test that can't find it:

```
    final widget = MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RadioListWidget(
          radioList: radiolist,
          onChange: (value) {
            selected = value;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );

      testWidgets('it behaves the same as tapping the text', (tester) async {
        await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
        debugDumpApp();
        await tester.tap(find.byType(Radio).first);
        expect(selected, 'radio 1');
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

```dart
 final radioFinder = find.byWidgetPredicate(
          (widget) => widget is Radio<int>,
        );
```

Comment: This works perfectly, you can then use it like so: expect(radioFinder, findsNWidgets(2));

Answer (score -1):

Replace your finder with this:

```
find.byType(Radio<String>().runtimeType)
```

Comment: Doesn't work since the `Radio()` constructor requires the arguments `onChanged`, `value` and `groupValue`.